# jquery animate and replacewith functions, in my ruby on rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-animate

In my 'review' div, 185 pixels in height, I have a link, 'Edit', which when clicked turns the div to 250 pixels, and the link changes to 'Cancel', and when clicked back to 185, and so on.

This code (in a js.erb file) works great for me ('Edit' link changes to 'Cancel'):

```
$('#review_<%=@review.id%>').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'edit') %>")
$('#review_<%=@review.id %>').animate({height:'250px'}, 300);
```

My #review div expands smoothly to 250 pixels. Now I'm trying to get the same effect going back to 185 pixels. But the height shrinks abruptly - there's no smooth transition:

```
$('#review_<%=@review.id%>').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript( review_block @review ) %>")
$('#review_<%=@review.id %>').animate({height:'185px'}, 300);
```

Any ideas how I can animate it smoothly? I tried putting 'html' instead of 'replaceWith' but it throws the contents of my div out of position. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you are losing the element on which jQuery has set the height when you call replaceWith.  To illustrate, say you had the following DOM:

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="review">
    <img src="review.gif"/>
    <input type="text"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you call `$('#review').animate({height: '180px'}, 300);` at the end the review div will now have a style set on it:

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="review" style="height:180px">
    <img src="review.gif"/>
    <input type="text"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you call `$('#review').replaceWith("<div id="review2"></div>");` you remove that element and the styling that is associated with it:

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="review2">
  </div>
</div>
```

You have two options.  One is that you can animate a style on an element that you aren't going to remove from the DOM.  You could possibly animate the parent of the element you are currently manipulating, in my example that would be `#page`.  That way when you replace the review element the styling isn't removed.

Another option would be to change the `review_block @review` to return just *the contents* of the review block instead of the whole thing.  I'm assuming right now that function returns something like this:

```
  <div id="review">
    <img src="review.gif"/>
    <input type="text"></input>
  </div>
```

You can change `review_block @review` to just return (again, my example) the following:

```
    <img src="review.gif"/>
    <input type="text"></input>
```

Then you can use the jQuery `html` function instead of `replaceWith` and you should keep both your style and not mess up your positioning.

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive reply. I'm just working through it now and will let you know....